# Replacing order by rand mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Are there any equivalents of `order by rand`?

Answer (score 0):

While link from @Sandro explains why `ORDER BY RAND()` is bad, it gives no real solutions.

You should try reading [this articles](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/). And if it is too "dry", or you want to learn more about SQL, then you should look up [SQL Antipatters](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book, or at least carefully look through authors [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back).